# Asset integration with Microsoft Azure Storage in Craft 3

Tags: assets, craft3, storage

I'm developing a site using the Craft 3 and I can't figure out how to connect assets with Microsoft Azure Storage.

I found plugin for Amazon S3 but not available similar plugin for azure.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You could try fronting Blob with [s3proxy](https://github.com/gaul/s3proxy) as a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any public Craft 3 plugins that integrate with Microsoft Azure Storage and I'm not seeing any on https://plugins.craftcms.com/, so at this point, you'd have to write your own.

There are several Azure Storage PHP libraries that you could use as a starting point:

https://packagist.org/packages/microsoft/azure-storage?query=microsoft%2Fazure